# How in-sync is the MapBox flavour of Leaflet with the FOSS version?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

How in-sync is the [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/) flavour of Leaflet with the [open source version](http://leafletjs.com/)?

I'm concerned that if I got with the MapBox sku, I'll be locking myself into a non-standard version, so things like ... are worrying me

- if there is a new feature in Leaflet, how soon does it appear in MapBox ... *assuming it does?*
- do plugin's work with both flavours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapbox.js extends Leaflet, which means that it [includes all of Leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/mb-pages/package.json#L15), plus a few extras like L.mapbox.featureLayer and L.mapbox.geocoder that make handling GeoJSON more convenient and add an interface to the Mapbox Geocoding API, respectively (there are more `L.mapbox` methods that you can read about on the [API documentation page](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/) and you can check out [release notes on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/mb-pages/CHANGELOG.md)). Because it includes all of Leaflet, Mapbox.js works with Leaflet plugins. Updates happen fairly quickly after an official Leaflet release (the primary maintainer of the Leaflet project works at Mapbox). Note that Mapbox.js tracks with official Leaflet releases, so Leaflet 1.0 won't be incorporated until it is out of beta.